# Google play console error, Pre-launch report details, Crashes and ANRs

Tags: android, google-play-console

java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with debug key (go/gsrlt)

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: Yes in play console

Comment: As mentionned by your error message, you signed your app with the debug key, and something is wong with this. Without details and with the poor informations you give, we can't help you more...

Comment: Please provide more details. You should ask a question, say what you are seeing where, what you have tried, etc.